# Which readings were changed in the 2010 Jouyou kanji reform?

Tags: kanji, readings, jōyō-kanji

I'm looking for pointers on which readings (on/kun) were changed in the 2010 reform. By that I mean which kanji has additional readings and which kanji has had one or more readings removed? Is there a document that summarizes these changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The official [改定常用漢字表](http://www.bunka.go.jp/seisaku/bunkashingikai/sokai/sokai_10/pdf/kaitei_kanji_toushin.pdf) ("Revised Jōyō Kanji Chart") itself contains this information.  It starts on page 169 of the document, which is page 203 of the PDF, under the heading 「現行「常用漢字表」からの変更点一覧」.

Comment: Getting a 404 on that.

Comment: @WillihamTotland I updated the link! :-)